# How can i set the background color for a python dataframe column header that i want to output to HTML?

Tags: python, html, pandas

I am trying to output a dataframe to the body of an email and set a background color for the column headers. So, for the random example below, I'd like the column headers (A,B,C,D) to have some background color. Can i do that with the styler object maybe? In the same way i've set the font to calibri?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML

dates = pd.date_range('20130101',periods=3)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3,4),index=dates,columns=list('ABCD'))

styles = [{'props':[("font-family", "Calibri")]}]
s = df.style.set_table_styles(styles)

html = s.hide_index().render()
with open("html_c.html","w") as fp:
   fp.write(html)

#*to display in a jupyter notebook*
display(HTML(html))
```

[image]

thanks in advance for any thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your `styles` list like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML

dates = pd.date_range('20130101',periods=3)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3,4),index=dates,columns=list('ABCD'))

styles = [{'props':[("font-family", "Calibri")]},
    ####   >>> begin
    {
       'selector': 'th',
       'props': [
           ('background-color', 'yellow')]
   }
   ####   >>> end
]

s = df.style.set_table_styles(styles)

html = s.hide_index().render()
with open("html_c.html","w") as fp:
   fp.write(html)

html = s.hide_index().render()
#*to display in a jupyter notebook*
display(HTML(html))[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

which will give

[image]

Comment: follow-up question: it looks great in Jupyter, but when i export it to email, i get white spaces between the cells. Would you know how to eliminate the white spaces?

Comment: What method are you using to export?

Comment: @bgilliam AFAIK the space is missing because the table has no border, you might want to add something to the `props` like `('border-style','solid'),('border-width','1px')`

Comment: @ ExplodingGayFish - Is there an option to select a specific header to color like only D?